# Dapper map multiple joins Sql Query

Tags: c#, sql, orm, mapping, dapper

I want to map complex object to dapper result from query which has two inner joins. I know we've solution to map one inner join but I want to map two inner joins result.

Here is the Scenario:

My Classes are:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string order_reference { get; set; }
    public string order_status { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int order_id { get; set; }
    public string product_number { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLineSize> OrderLineSizes { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineSize
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int order_line_id { get; set; }
    public string size_name { get; set; }
}
```

> Order has OrderLines as List and OrderLine as OrderLineSizes as List.

Now, Here is my query base on that I want to populate `List<Order>` with correct data:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders_mstr o
INNER JOIN order_lines ol ON o.id = ol.order_id
INNER JOIN order_line_size_relations ols ON ol.id = ols.order_line_id
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Order>();
            connection.Query<Order, OrderLine, Order>(@"
                    SELECT o.*, ol.*
                    FROM orders_mstr o
                    INNER JOIN order_lines ol ON o.id = ol.order_id                    
                    ", (o, ol) => {
                    Order orderDetail;
                    if (!lookup.TryGetValue(o.id, out orderDetail))
                    {
                        lookup.Add(o.id, orderDetail = o);
                    }
                    if (orderDetail.OrderLines == null)
                        orderDetail.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
                    orderDetail.OrderLines.Add(ol);
                    return orderDetail;
                }).AsQueryable();

            var resultList = lookup.Values;
```

Using this, I can successfully map order object with OrderLine but I want to populate OrderLineSizes as well with correct data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried my best and solve it.

Here is the more easy and accurate solution as per me.:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, OrderDetail>();
            var lookup2 = new Dictionary<int, OrderLine>();
            connection.Query<OrderDetail, OrderLine, OrderLineSize, OrderDetail>(@"
                    SELECT o.*, ol.*, ols.*
                    FROM orders_mstr o
                    INNER JOIN order_lines ol ON o.id = ol.order_id
                    INNER JOIN order_line_size_relations ols ON ol.id = ols.order_line_id           
                    ", (o, ol, ols) =>
            {
                OrderDetail orderDetail;
                if (!lookup.TryGetValue(o.id, out orderDetail))
                {
                    lookup.Add(o.id, orderDetail = o);
                }
                OrderLine orderLine;
                if (!lookup2.TryGetValue(ol.id, out orderLine))
                {
                    lookup2.Add(ol.id, orderLine = ol);
                    orderDetail.OrderLines.Add(orderLine);
                }
                orderLine.OrderLineSizes.Add(ols);
                return orderDetail;
            }).AsQueryable();

            var resultList = lookup.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: This code will not work actually if we use the domain classes of OP. It is due to `OrderLines` and `OrderLineSizes` are null, hence, you will get NullReferenceException in the runtime on lines: `orderDetail.OrderLines.Add(orderLine);` and `orderLine.OrderLineSizes.Add(ols);`. Initialize each of them next line to `lookup.Add` and `lookup2.Add`, or simply use C#6 auto-property initializer on the class level.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done by `QueryMultiple` but because your question includes `INNER JOIN` I don't use it.

```
public Dictionary<int, Order> GetOrderLookup()
{
    var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Order>();

    const string sql = @"   SELECT  o.id,
                                    o.order_reference,
                                    o.order_status,

                                    ol.id,
                                    ol.order_id,
                                    ol.product_number,

                                    ols.id,
                                    ols.order_line_id,
                                    ols.size_name
                            FROM    orders_mstr o
                            JOIN    order_lines ol ON o.id = ol.order_id
                            JOIN    order_line_size_relations ols ON ol.id = ols.order_line_id";

    List<Order> orders = null;
    using (var connection = OpenConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        orders = connection.Query<Order, OrderLine, OrderLineSize, Order>(sql, (order, orderLine, orderLizeSize) =>
        {
            orderLine.OrderLineSizes = new List<OrderLineSize> { orderLizeSize };
            order.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>() { orderLine };
            return order;
        },
        null, commandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();
    }

    if (orders == null || orders.Count == 0)
    {
        return lookup;
    }

    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        var contians = lookup.ContainsKey(order.id);
        if (contians)
        {
            var newLinesToAdd = new List<OrderLine>();
            var existsLines = lookup[order.id].OrderLines;
            foreach (var existsLine in existsLines)
            {
                foreach (var newLine in order.OrderLines)
                {
                    if (existsLine.id == newLine.id)
                    {
                        existsLine.OrderLineSizes.AddRange(newLine.OrderLineSizes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newLinesToAdd.Add(newLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            existsLines.AddRange(newLinesToAdd);
        }
        else
        {
            lookup.Add(order.id, order);
        }
    }

    return lookup;
}
```

Comment: @DanielTshuva Can you tell me why Order is in the connection.Query command twice?  Thanks.

Comment: @johnny - In the select query the first statement is to get Order properties (id, order_reference, order_status) -> This for first Order, the second Order is the OUT type. Note, that we query for 3 Select statements for 3 types, but in the connection.Query we provider 4 type -> the last Type is the out Type. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to use Dapper to get a big data for calculating somethings. This is my dapper extension method to join 3 table in _RepositoryBase.cs file.

```
    public List<Tuple<T, T2, T3, T4>> QueryMultiple<T2, T3, T4>(string sql, object param)
        where T2 : class
        where T3 : class
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(GetConnStr()))
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();

            var query = con.Query<T, T2, T3, T4, Tuple<T, T2, T3, T4>>(sql, (t, t2, t3, t4) => Tuple.Create(t, t2, t3, t4), param);

            //if (query.Count() == 0)
            //    return new List<T>();

            var data = query.ToList();

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

            return data;
        }
    }
```

Then, this function will help you to get sql joined data via dapper.

```
    public List<Table1> GetSqlJoinedDataViaDaper(int customerId)
    {
        var repo = new GenericRepository<T_LOOKUP>();
        var sql = @"select table1.ID Table1ID, table1.*,
                    table2.ID Table2ID, table2.*,
                    table3.ID Table3ID, table3.*
                    from dbo.Table1 table1 (nolock)
                    left outer join dbo.Table2 table2 (nolock) on table2.ID=table1.FKTable2ID
                    left outer join dbo.Table3 table3 (nolock) on table3.ID=table1.FKTable3ID
                    where table1.CustomerID=@p1 ";

        var resultWithJoin = repo.QueryMultiple<Table1, Table2, Table3>(sql,
            new { p1 = 1, splitOn = "Table1ID,Table2ID,Table3ID" }).ToList();

        var retval = new List<Table1>();
        foreach (var item in resultWithJoin)
        {
            Table1 t1 = item.Item2; //After first split
            t1.Table2 = item.Item3; //After Table2ID split
            t1.Table3 = item.Item4; //After Table3ID split

            retval.Add(t1);
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Summary:
Write your select and insert split between tables. Say splits to Dapper and get your data. I used this and worked better than Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm having issues with the `QueryMultiple()` function: `The type or namespace name T could not be found`. When I change it to `List<Tuple<T, T2, T3>> QueryMultiple<T, T2, T3>(string sql, object param)` it compiles, but the calling function does not execute as expected.