# .NET Core Dapper: Get data by joining multiple tables on combined primary keys as object with list of objects

Tags: c#, dapper

I've been using Dapper to access data from an older database with a specific structure and am having trouble with some issues. Many of them have some sort of answer but I can't seem to combine the solutions, here we go:

1. The object is to be created out of 3 different tables (inner join)
2. The objects are to be created in a nested object (a main object with lists of sub objects)
3. The required tables have combined primary keys (no separate unique keys)
4. The objects have identical property names (I'm not sure that this is an issue, haven't come far enough)

```cs
public class MainObject {
    public long Id1 { get; set; }
    public long Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Id3 { get; set; }
    public List<SubObject1> Subobject1 { get; set; }
    public List<SubObject2> Subobject2 { get; set; }
    public string OtherProps { get; set; }
}

public class SubObject1 {
    public long Id1 { get; set; }
    public long Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Id3 { get; set; }
}

public class SubObject1 {
    public long Id1 { get; set; }
    public long Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Id3 { get; set; }
}
```

I've been trying to combine issues 1 and 2 [as described in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43975147/6761698). After that I've been trying to add issue 3 [as described in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55098842/6761698), but haven't been able to make it work. An error I get frequently is `System.ArgumentException: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id`, so I'm not sure I even understand the entire concept.

My query (which is able to return multiple rows) is structured as:

```sql
SELECT MainObject.*, SubObject1.*, SubObject2.*
FROM MainObject
INNER JOIN SubObject1 ON MainObject.Id1 = SubObject1.Id1
    AND MainObject.Id2 = SubObject1.Id2 AND MainObject.Id3 = SubObject1.Id3
INNER JOIN SubObject2 ON MainObject.Id1 = SubObject2.Id1
    AND MainObject.Id2 = SubObject2.Id2 AND MainObject.Id3 = SubObject2.Id3
WHERE MainObject.OtherProps = 'SomeValue'
```

Preferable the output would be of type `List<MainObject>`.

I'm open to all remarks and hints

E: The reason we chose Dapper is because we're reluctant to use Entity Framework and our current mapping has performance issues. At the moment we query for List, which loops and queries for every SubObject1 and SubObject2 separately (thus executing a lot of queries).

Answer (score 0):

Good morning mate

Look at your simple query I suggest that you use the Linq, it would be easier and have the resource you want ...

The dapper is used to query more complex and heavy ones where you select the fields eg: "SELEC a.id as a_id, B.id as b_id" and then manually map.

I suggest in this case to use Linq.

Linq example:

```
  var blogs1 = context.Blogs
                       .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments))
                       .Include(b => b.Users)
                       .Include(b => b.Users.City)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I don't seem to understand how my issue translates to the Linq example? In my understanding, to use Linq, I'd have to query on context (set through Entity Framework?) or through a seeded object? I am reluctant to add Entity Framework to the existing project, which is the reason I chose Dapper initially. Also, your query doesn't take into account that my objects are nested, so I'm not sure this would even work out? Could you elaborate, or suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to combine the different solutions for a while I stumbled on [an article that took a different approach](https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172). Instead of trying to map the objects from a single query, it split up the joins in a `QueryMultiple` statement. I then used Linq to map the multiple objects as one.

```cs
public List<MainObject> GetMainObjects(string conn)
{
    List<MainObject> mos = new List<MainObject>();
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlMapper.GridReader results = connection.QueryMultiple(
            $"SELECT * FROM MainObject; " +
            $"SELECT * FROM SubObject1; " +
            $"SELECT * FROM SubObject2;");

        mos = results.Read<MainObject>().ToList();
                
        IEnumerable<SubObject1> so1s = results.Read<SubObject1>();
        mos.ForEach(mo => mo.SubObject1 = new List<SubObject1>());
        mos.ForEach(mo => mo.SubObject1.AddRange(
            so1s.Where(so1 => mo.Id1 == so1.Id1 && mo.Id2 == so1.Id2 && mo.Id3.Equals(so1.Id3))
       ));

        IEnumerable<SubObject2> so2s = results.Read<SubObject2>();
        mos.ForEach(mo => mo.SubObject2 = new List<SubObject2>());
        mos.ForEach(mo => mo.SubObject2.AddRange(
            so2s.Where(so2 => mo.Id1 == so2.Id1 && mo.Id2 == so2.Id2 && mo.Id3.Equals(so2.Id3))
        ));
    }

    return mos;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: verify performance impact, Select * from a table then join in memory, this is evil for performance. what if you have a million rows. On small numbers (less than 1000 row per table) could be fine. In my experience mixing entity framework and dapper is nothing bad, use the best for your scenario.